# escape/replace special character when reading FlatFile

Tags: spring-batch

I have an itemWriter configured with `TAB` as delimiter

```
@Bean
    public ItemWriter<ObjectFileRow> objectItemWriter() {

        ......
        delLineAgg.setDelimiter(";");
        .......
        return writer;
    }
```

I'have some lignes contains data with ";"

```
391494  2013    1       9-820   9-2510  &uml;PR Tesme
391495  2013    0       9-9849  9-2510  PR  Hello
```

The probleme here when ligne 1 is wirten i will have result as shown :

```
391494;2013;1;9-820;9-2510;&uml;PR Tesme
```

The problem here is that these files will be tested with another programs, this programs is looking to find exactly `6 records` but as you can see he consider `&uml;PR Tesme` as two records.

what is the best approach to replace `;` inside this record `&uml;PR    Tesme` to be `&uml PR   Tesme`.

- redear with regular expression to escape all `;` in records when there is reading operation
- processor which verify records if they contains `;` and then replace it with a `space` ?
- any other ideas ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Processor should work on the records, business logic should be present in Processor. So, processor should check if there is anything wrong in the record then fix it or bypass it.